# asymmetrical rows and columns in table with div's

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using divs to make tables (div's because I had some complicated design).
I want to my first row to have multiple columns and second row is just a single row which spans through the whole row and next row is again a multiple column row.

This first row, second row is not static, its dynamically decided from data.

My css:

```
#table-holder {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
    border: solid 2px #b7ddf2;
    background: #ebf4fb;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

#row {
    display: table-row;
    border: solid 2px #b7ddf2;
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
}

#column {
    display: table-cell;
    border: solid 2px #b7ddf2;
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
}
```

my html:

```
<div id="table-holder">
  <div id="row">
    <div id="column">
    </div>
    <div id="column">
    </div>
    <div id="column">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="random">
      I want this to span for my whole row, instead of just 1st column.
  </div>
  <div id="row">
    <div id="column">
    </div>
    <div id="column">
    </div>
    <div id="column">
    </div>
  </div>
```

any ideas ?

Thank you

Comment: You should not be duplicating an id attribute. By definition these should be unique to a single object on the screen. CSS won't complain but any js would. Use classes instead for things that aren't strictly singleton.

Comment: ok. I never knew that. Thank you. will changing the id attribute to class will fix the issue ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML colspan in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403990/html-colspan-in-css)

Answer (score -1):

You may be running into trouble because this really isn't what divs are made for. They're block-level elements. If you want to create a table, you should be using table, tr td, etc.

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/zjL3N/) gets your middle row to span the width of the container but I think it may take away the functionality you were looking for.

I'd recommend investigating floats and a clearfix method for the columns if you're set on using divs.