# Column span for display: table-cell

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to span elements with `display: table-cell` across columns as you would with a table `<td>` using `colspan="100%"`?

Comment: Yis I tried, didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, please realize that doing `colspan = "100%"` is actually equivalent to `colspan = "100"` — browsers just make the cell span all columns in case the number of columns is less than 100.

In the general case, to get a a cell that spans the whole table, check out [`<caption>`](http://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_caption_tag.cfm), although it has more limited use than one would hope.

As for your question, you basically can't achieve what you're trying to achieve without using actual HTML tables. There are [many other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403990/html-colspan-in-css) on StackOverflow that have answers providing hacks, though.