# Making colspans in CSS made tables

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have the following form which is made not using the standard `<table>` tag but with CSS table(`display:table, display:table-row, display: table-cell`). Till here no problem occurs but then I need some colspans in CSS which I am not able to apply. I used `column-span` but it didn't worked!

**HTML:**

```
<div id="form">
<br/><br/>
    <form id="form_container">
        <span class="row">
            <span class="cell"><select></select></span>
            <span class="cell"><input type="text" /></span>
        </span>
        <span class="row">
            <span class="cell"><input type="email" /></span>
        </span>
        <span class="row">
            <span class="cell"><select></select></span>
        </span>
        <span class="row">
            <span class="cell"><select></select></span>
        </span>
        <span class="row">
            <span class="cell"><select></select></span>
        </span>
        <span class="row">
            <span class="cell"><input type="text" /></span>
            <span class="cell"><select></select></span>
        </span>
        <span class="row">
        <span class="cell"><input type="checkbox" /><b>I have read the</b> <a>Terms & Conditions</a></span>
        </span>
        <input type="image" src="img/send_button.png" />
    </form>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#form_container {
    display: table;
}

.row {
    display: table-row;
}

.cell {
    display: table-cell;
}

input, select {
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Mx7Wc/)

I want the colspan on the rows which have only one cell. Is this possible with CSS or not?

Comment: Try this link to a discussion on the same topic:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403990/html-colspan-in-css

Comment: @Erin No, that's not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having `div` dressed up as a `table` smells wrong in the first place, I would avoid it. However, if your target are the modern browsers you could use :nth-child pseudo selector.

```
/* one item */
.cell:first-child:nth-last-child(1) {
     width: 100%;
}

/* two items */
.cell:first-child:nth-last-child(2) {
    width: 50%;
}
```

Does this fiddle looks like your expected result : http://jsfiddle.net/dZuAh/3/ ?