# make cell span two colums css3 (no tables)

Tags: css

I am trying to build a table purely in CSS. Have succeded so far, even though I have one issue:
How do I make a cell span two columns?

I made this fiddle, and in the top where the "XXXXXX" with the grey background is, I simply cannot make it span the width of my box. I tried to use column-span, but it did not work, so I guess I have redesign it in another fashion .. just how?

I am using this code, but the content of tabledata_lang stops just where tablecells below stop:

```
#tabledata_lang {
padding: 6px;
width:100%;
}
```

See my fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/T7wU2/

(Probably easier to see my issue here...)

Hope someone has some input..

Regards
Regin

Comment: Just a note, you have invalid markup, id attributes should be unique in a HTML page

Comment: use classes instead of ids. Also I looked around and I didn't see any elements with the id of `#tabledata_lang`. Finally I believe there should be a colspan attribute where you can specify how many columns you want your td to span.

Comment: also what do you mean by "no tables" and "purely in CSS"? your fiddle shows a regular HTML table

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML colspan in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403990/html-colspan-in-css)

Comment: @koala_dev Ah yes, sorry, I first build it all in DIVs but then abandoned it. But you are of course right, i do use HTML. But my idea was, that I wanted to do all the styling in CSS. Without the "colspan="2"".

Comment: @Regin refer to the question linked by @gilly3 for a discussion on the use of `colspan`. What I would advise is to use HTML tables only to display tabular data (and I don't see any issue with using colspan), if what you need is to display content in a grid manner, then look for a CSS framework that provides a grid system such as [twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the [colspan](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/td) attribute

```
<td colspan="2"></td>
```

This will make a cell span 2 columns

Comment: Thanks - but If I do not want to use the colspan="2" directly in the HTML code, but would like to use CSS to make the cell span the two rows.. can I do that - I cant seem to find any code that does it.