# How is equivalent align and colspan table's tag in .css style file

Tags: html, css

How is equivalent align and colspan table's tag in .css style file?
For example

```
 <table colspan="2" align="center">
```

Comment: They are different things. That's why they both exist instead of just one of them. You probably need to explain why you;re asking for this to be considered a valid question.

Comment: Same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403990/html-colspan-in-css

Comment: @Vlad Noname, Check my answer. Brief explanation

Answer (score 0):

Let me elaborate a bit.

**colspan** defines the number of columns a cell should span in a group of columns.

Example :[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PFmDj/)

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Cell A</td>
    <td>Cell B</td>
    <td>Cell C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">Cell ABC</td>
  </tr>
</td>
</table>
```

In this example i have specified colspan="3" for the second row `<td>`. Hence this `<td>` will span 3 columns of the table.

***align*** is a style attribute which has 3 options left, right, centre. This will determine where you want to place the table on your page.

Example:

```
<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>Cell A</td>
        <td>Cell B</td>
        <td>Cell C</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```