# mixed rows in a html tables

Tags: html, css

I have a html table with 1st row containing 5 blocks and 2nd row containing 2 blocks.

The 2nd row 2nd block contains 5 radio buttons as well.

I need the 2 row 2nd block to be spanned across 1st rows last 4 blocks

```
http://jsfiddle.net/8T5RZ/
```

HTML Code

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <div class="tabular-div"></div>
        <div class="tabular-div"></div>
        <div class="tabular-div"></div>
        <div class="tabular-div"></div>
        <div class="tabular-div"></div>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <div class="tabular-div"></div>
        <div class="tabular-div">
            <input type="radio" />
            <input type="radio" />
            <input type="radio" />
        </div>
    </tr>
</table>
```

css code

```
.tabular-div {
    background-color:green;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:5px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: use `<td>` elements and set attribute `colspan="4"`? Or are you trying to avoid `<td>` for some reason?

Comment: I'm not even sure if it's valid to use `div` in place of `td`.

Comment: I agree with @TreeTree - if you are going to use `<table>` as your parent element, then keep things consistent and use `<tr>` and `<td>`.  You can achieve this layout both with and without tables, and many people would encourage you to avoid using `<table>`to lay out content.

Comment: According to the W3C definition, a `<tr>` element acts as a container for table cells (`<td>` or `<th>`). A `<div>` should not be the child of `<tr>` but of a `<td>` or `<th>`.

Comment: @Nick:Yes, Im trying to avoid <td>..This is a existing framework and thats how it works(ie; using div within rows)..Trying to integrate a new row within it.

Comment: You *have* to use a `<th>` or `<td>` as the child of a `<tr>` element. No way around it.

Comment: You may want to review the following/previous discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403990/html-colspan-in-css If this is an existing framework, then, there is a problem of a serious nature!

Comment: If you can't use <td> then use another wrapping div instead of the <tr>, e.g.: <div class="parent"><div class="child"></div></div>