# colspan equalent in css?

Tags: html, css

There's a first table row that looks like this:

```
....

<tr>
   <th colspan="2">Add a category</th>
</tr>

...
```

It renders correctly. However I want it to be without `colspan` attribute, but styled in CSS instead. And the reason for that is because there are a lot of similar tables, so it wouldn't require to define the attribute over and over again (just adhering to DRY principle)

I just want it to be as:

```
<tr>
   <th>Add a category</th>
</tr>

// CSS
table th:first-child {
    /* Pseudo attr */
    colspan : 2px;
}
```

I've tried playing with `float`, `padding` and `width` with no success. Is there any way to do that in pure CSS?

Comment: Note that the markup in the question is invalid; apparently `tr` with `th` inside was meant. That would be inadequate as per HTML specs, since `th` is a header for cells in the same column or row, not for rows after it; `td` should be used. And `colspan` HTML attribute should be used, because this is about the structure of the table (one cell spans several slots).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no way to do that with pure CSS because `colspan` is really more layout than style.

According to [this](http://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/514a02da62c1a14363000733), It appears that it was supported on some past browsers, but seems to really be not recommended and unsupported in the present day.

Answer (score -2):

There are numerous answers to this question: for example you can check the solution described [here](http://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/514a02da62c1a14363000733).
It involves the use of column-span css attribute, but as mentioned it won't work on old browsers.

```
column-span: 4; /* W3C */
-webkit-column-span: 4; /* Safari & Chrome */
-moz-column-span: 4; /* Firefox */
-ms-column-span: 4; /* Internet Explorer */
-o-column-span: 4; /* Opera */
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403990/html-colspan-in-css) you can find a discussion about this point. I agree with the point that a colspan is more structure than appearance and so should stay in HTML, but it is a personal opinion. On the same thread, you can find a solution using divs, if you like.

Comment: What would these be set on in the example case, and how would they solve the problem?

Comment: This property is out of the table's scope as it is intended to work with column layouts:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-span.asp

Comment: The end of that "answer" says "However, this will only work in current generation browsers. I would suggest not setting the colspan in CSS, but the choice is yours."