# How to center and span table heading (row)

Tags: html, css

I need to know how to center and span the "MyTable" heading. Can it be down with both HTML (the center tag) and CSS? I tried playing around with text-align, positioning etc but I couldn't get what I want.

[image: Table examples]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>

            th {
                border: 1px solid red;
                text-align: center;
            }

            td {
                border: 1px dashed black;
                color: red;
            }

            table {

                font-family: Calibri;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr><th>My Table</th></tr>
            <tr><th>FName</th><th>LName</th><th>Age</th></tr>
            <tr><td>Derp</td><td>Derpania</td><td>69</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Buzz</td><td>Killington</td><td>42</td></tr>
        </table>
    </body> 
</html>
```

If there's a solution in both CSS and HTML, please give me both.

Comment: Never heard of `colspan`?

Comment: Actually, no. I just started learning HTML and CSS and I didn't come across colspan. Thank you anyway...

Comment: Fair enough; it seems not as primary a function as I believed. Inspecting the first 10 or so 'html tables for beginners' links, `colspan`, and its vertical counterpart `rowspan`, is only first mentioned in link #3.

Comment: - This may interest you: [HTML colspan in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403990/html-colspan-in-css) (and the consensus seems to be "you cannot"/"you should not").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `colspan` to the `th` element.

```
    <table>
        <tr><th colspan="3">My Table</th></tr>
        <tr><th>FName</th><th>LName</th><th>Age</th></tr>
        <tr><td>Derp</td><td>Derpania</td><td>69</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Buzz</td><td>Killington</td><td>42</td></tr>
    </table>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y0tyapz6/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Seems weird that I didn't come across colspan.

Comment: You are welcome! `colspan` is the only way to combine table columns.