# merge existing columns using CSS

Tags: css, stylesheet

I have a table. The table is generated by some server side code which I can't change but I can add some CSS to style.

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
 <td>row 1 column 1</td>
 <td>row 1 column 2</td>

</tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Is there a way of merging the two columns using CSS and not JQuery

```
  |row1 column1 |row 1 column 2 |
  |             |               |
```

get an output like

```
| row 1 column2  |
|                |
```

Comment: Can you show an example output with respect to the HTML used?

Comment: You might be looking for the colspan attribute?

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp

Comment: This does not make much sense... Just write everything inside the same `td`

Comment: maybe  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403990/html-colspan-in-css

Comment: as your example shows u wnat to show the 2 columns as one but without any style it is difficult to distinguish between columns.  http://jsfiddle.net/q8mne8ts/   what do u want to do exactly

Answer (score 5):

This isn't possible within CSS, even when you say they're block level elements.

They are still two separate elements and HTML will render them as such.

As shown below:

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.block * {
  display: block;
}
.border-collapse {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>row 1 column 1</td>
      <td>row 1 column 2</td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="block">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>row 1 column 1</td>
      <td>row 1 column 2</td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="border-collapse">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>row 1 column 1</td>
      <td>row 1 column 2</td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I believe you are going to have to try and change the html, use the [`colspan`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp) attribute:

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">Here I need a cell by all width</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>TD 1</td>
      <td>TD 2</td>
      <td>TD 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

> The colspan attribute defines the number of columns a cell should span.

There is a related attribute [`rowspan`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp) that achieves the same for rows.

One last dirty option is to always set one of the elements to `display: none` and the other `width: 100%`

```css
table {
  width: 400px;
}
table tr td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table.td_hide tr td:first-child {
  display: none;
}

table.td_hide tr td:last-child {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Row One</td>
    <td>Row Two</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="td_hide">
  <tr>
    <td>Row One</td>
    <td>Row Two</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The solution works for me if I set the colspan for the second column I.e. colspan:2 and set the display:none for the first column . Is there a way to add a way to set the colspan using CSS using the content attribute.

Comment: Sadly colspan is a html only element. I have come up with another alternative if you look at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to display the elements as block elements like this:

```
table, tbody, tr, td {
    display: block;
}
```