# How to create an integrated row in the table?

Tags: html, css

I have a table like this:

```
+----------+----------+
| record 1 | record 2 |
+----------+----------+
| record 3 | record 4 |
+----------+----------+
| record 5 | record 6 |
+----------+----------+
```

Now I want to add a integrated row in the first of it, something like this structure:

```
+---------------------+
|     Table Name      |
+----------+----------+
| record 1 | record 2 |
+----------+----------+
| record 3 | record 4 |
+----------+----------+
| record 5 | record 6 |
+----------+----------+
```

---

Here is my codes:

**HTML:**

```
<table cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Table Name
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>record 1</td>
        <td>record 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>record 3</td>
        <td>record 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>record 5</td>
        <td>record 6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
td{    
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

Also here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/619sooj0/).

So, How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `colspan` attribute.

```css
td{    
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            Table Name
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>record 1</td>
        <td>record 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>record 3</td>
        <td>record 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>record 5</td>
        <td>record 6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks +1. has `colspan` a equivalent in CSS?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It's something related to HTML. You can also see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403990/html-colspan-in-css

Answer (score 2):

Use a `thead` with `colspan` to differentiate the content from the label. Make the rest of your content in the `tbody`:

```
<table cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Table Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>record 1</td>
            <td>record 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>record 3</td>
            <td>record 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>record 5</td>
            <td>record 6</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And slightly adjust the CSS:

```
td, th {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/619sooj0/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `colspan`.

```
<table cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            Table Name
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>record 1</td>
        <td>record 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>record 3</td>
        <td>record 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>record 5</td>
        <td>record 6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6jc4fg63/).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`caption`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-caption-element) elements for table titles:

> The `caption` element represents the title of the `table` that is its
>   parent

As explained in [Tables in the visual formatting model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#model), caption boxes are rendered as normal block boxes inside the table wrapper box, but outside the table box:

> [image]

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
}
caption, td {    
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>Table Name</caption>
  <tr>  <td>record 1</td> <td>record 2</td>  </tr>
  <tr>  <td>record 3</td> <td>record 4</td>  </tr>
  <tr>  <td>record 5</td> <td>record 6</td>  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yeah, Seems nice ...! +1

Comment: I don't like that the caption border doesn't collapse with others when using `border-collapse: collapse`, though.