# Substitute for rowspan with css

Tags: css, html-table

Hi,

I am trying to replace my table with divs and CSS but I cant figure out a way to mimic the rowspan attribute. This is my original code:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>some content</td>
  <td>some more content</td>
  <td rowspan="2">THIS is A COLUMN</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="2">SINGLE CELL ROW</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

With CSS:

```
<header>
 <section>
  <div>some content</div>
  <div>some more content</div>
  <div rowspan="2">THIS is A COLUMN</div>
 </section>
 <section>
  <div>SINGLE CELL ROW</div>
 </section>
</header>

header {display:table;}
section {display:table-row;}
div {display:table-cell;}
```

but it wont work because the div at the bottom will not go all the way below the rowspanned div as expected. Is there any CSS solution for this?

Thank you.

This is NOT A DUPLICATE. Im asking for ROWSPAN not colspan only.

Comment: grid systems like bootstrap or flexbox

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML colspan in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403990/html-colspan-in-css)

Comment: NO, ITS NOT A DUPLICATE. Im asking about ROWSPAN. Its not the same as colspan...

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want, by changing your HTML markup a bit and using `Flexbox`

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
body {
  margin: 0
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse
}
td {
  border: 1px red solid
}
header {
  display: flex
}
section {
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 0;
}
section > div {
  border: 1px solid green;
  font-size: 16px
}
section:first-of-type div {
  border-right: 0
}
section:first-of-type div:not(:last-of-type) {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-flex;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
section:last-of-type div {
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex
}
```

```html
<h2>TABLE</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>some content</td>
    <td>some more content</td>
    <td rowspan="2">THIS is A COLUMN</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">SINGLE CELL ROW</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br />
<hr />

<h2>DIV</h2>

<header>
  <section>
    <div>some content</div>
    <div>some more content</div>
    <div>SINGLE CELL ROW</div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div>THIS is A COLUMN</div>
  </section>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks but the goal is to preserve the same order in the html structure

Comment: @CainNuke I just change one div to another. Why you need to keep that structure?

Comment: because the content in the column has more priority than the one in the single cell row.

Comment: So? still can't see no reason for not changing the html markup. Its not a semantic problem. This change won't affect the indexation in searches so why again?

Comment: Its my navigation, I want it as close to the top as possible.

Comment: The output is the same, That isn't enough reason. I tried to help you by giving you a working solution.

Comment: Its okay, I appreciate your help anyway. Call it nitpicking if you want but I wanted to preserve the same order. I was almost sure it was not possible to achieve the rowspan effect with css only but I asked anyway just in case.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.parent{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.child{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid #444;
}

.row{
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
    <div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="row">
      <div>some content</div>
      <div>some more content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
       <div>SINGLE CELL ROW</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="row">
      <div>THIS is A COLUMN</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: Thank you but the column is missing?

Comment: I think you'd have to change up the HTML for that

Comment: That could be a problem. So in other words its impossible to get rowspan with CSS?

Comment: You are changing the order of the html structure which I dont intend.

Answer (score 0):

To do that table in flexbox, you could wrap each part that forms a row or a column

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>some content</div>
      <div>some more content</div>
    </div>
    <div>THIS is A COLUMN</div>
  </div>
  <div>SINGLE CELL ROW</div>
</div>
```

Then you can build `nowrap` rows and columns with flexbox to resemble your table

```
body div { border: 1px solid #999; margin: 0; }
body > div { display: flex; flex-flow: row nowrap; margin-top: 10px; }
body > div > div { display: flex; flex-flow: column nowrap; flex: 1 1 0; }
body > div > div > div { display: flex; flex-flow: row nowrap; flex: 1 1 1;}
body > div > div > div > div { flex: 1 1 0; }
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/oo5UrUMgI85myujt5L6s?p=preview

Comment: Not bad but you are changing the order of the html structure.