# CSS table with colspan

Tags: css, css-tables

How I can create this grid without html tables (using css tables for example).

```
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+
|   |       |
+-----------+
```

As you can see in last row, I need colspan=2 and I don't know how do it without standart tables... Because I need fluid width of columns - stretching for the content width.

P.s. Sorry if question is duplicate, but I'm not found answer with my grid...
This answer not work with my grid! [HTML colspan in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403990/html-colspan-in-css)

P.s.s. Please, see the difference https://jsfiddle.net/vt9jho53/

Comment: You could make use of Bootstrap to achieve this

Comment: this answer not working with grid which I need. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403990/html-colspan-in-css

Comment: With `display: table` you can't. But you can use frameworks like foundation or bootstrap (foundation is better) to achieve it

Comment: I use bootstrap, but Im not understend how create my grid with it... Bootstrap using floats, this not works as table columns

Comment: @user3449979 There is features like offset ,pull etc in Bootstrap

Comment: @ARUN but I need fluid width of colums (stretching for the content width)... this promlem. Because we using different languages and content width is different too.

Comment: @user3449979 from the design, I think you can do it easily , try

Comment: @user3449979 check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38393869/2724173

Comment: <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-8"></div>
    </div>
</div>

Comment: @user3449979 go to this site , you can visually create the grid easily  http://shoelace.io/

Comment: no need to make complete grid i think you can do something like on this way https://jsfiddle.net/1nmg5208/

Comment: Really not understand how ) You can see difference https://jsfiddle.net/vt9jho53/