# Colspan of css display table did not work

Tags: html, css

I have already tired to fix the colspan in the display table in CSS.

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table-row {
  display: table-row;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.table-row.colspan {
  display: block;
}
.table-row.colspan .table-cell {
  display: block;
  width: 200%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">
      top left cell
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      top right cell
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      top right cell
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      top right cell
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      top right cell
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      top right cell
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell colspan">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell colspan">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell colspan">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">
      bottom left cell
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      bottom right cell
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      bottom left cell
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      bottom right cell
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      bottom left cell
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      bottom right cell
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I take the colspan behavior of the second row in the table? Thanks in advance.

https://codepen.io/mdshohelrana/pen/WNNxBqP

Comment: https://codepen.io/hardik_g_/pen/ExxyBPN please check

Comment: @blurryfaceblueberry, Both are not the same. Please see the whole problem then and write the comment.

Comment: @Hardik's, Great

Comment: Why are you not using CSS grid?

Comment: @connexo, Our company has taken a decision that uses div table.

Comment: @Hardik's, here is the complete solution https://codepen.io/mdshohelrana/pen/ZEEOdOb

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean with "colspan behaviour"?

It's not possible to reproduce the HTML `colspan` attribute in tables in CSS und `display: table-*`, because it's a structural thing not a style thing. Plus `colspan` requires a number parameter to determine the number of columns to span, which you don't have.

What are you trying to do anyway? If you want to use a table (for tabular data) then use HTML `table`/`tr`/`td` elements and the colspan attribute.

If you want to have a table like (page) layout, then you should be using [css grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids) with which you can do `colspan`-like designs.

In any case you shouldn't be alot of divs and using class names such as `table-row/cell`etc. Class names should [semantically](https://maintainablecss.com/chapters/semantics/) describe the *content* not the *look* of elements.

Comment: Updated my code snippet.

Comment: @Shohel Great. Unfortunatly the update doesn't address my questions/remarks.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403990/html-colspan-in-css)

There is no simple CSS property that we can provide for colspan (As far as I know).
I think using table tag is more efficient and understandable.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Sum: $180</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp You can refer here.

Answer (score 1):

I could simulate a hack with setting float and width. Maybe it can be used in your design. But I'm not sure if it'll work the same on all platforms. Adding a width to the whole table and setting the colspan width the same with the table would be a bit more secure for this. Updated the answer with the width set.

The important part for width's to match is the `box-sizing: border-box` setting. As it would differ the gaps between two cells and one cell in a row, this should be set.

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 600px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.table-row {
  display: table-row;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.table-row.colspanned
{
  float: left;
  margin: -1px 0;
  width: 600px;
}

.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.table-cell.colspan {
  margin-top: -1px;
  margin-bottom: -1px;  
  width: 200px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">
      top left cell
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      top right cell
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      top right cell
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      top right cell
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      top right cell
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      top right cell
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row colspanned">
    <div class="table-cell colspan">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell colspan">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell colspan">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">
      bottom left cell
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      bottom right cell
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      bottom left cell
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      bottom right cell
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      bottom left cell
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      bottom right cell
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Updated my code snippet.

Comment: Ok but nothing changes, just specify the width of the cells to `total width / 3`. The main idea is the same.

Comment: Did not work your solution, When I add 6 column

Comment: Updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can solve it by two approaches:

1. Use `display:table-row-group` and then for cell specify `display:table-caption`. but I am struggling with setting border on right side in this case.
   Fiddle for same is below:

http://jsfiddle.net/hsbokxv4/

2. You can manipulate using javascript. Fiddle is below (Though I am not fan of this approach):

http://jsfiddle.net/emilianolch/5nvxv5ko/

Comment: Updated my code snippet.