# Colspan works inline but not in CSS (tables)

Tags: html, css, html-table

Thanks for helping out. I've searched for the answer to this for a while because it seems pretty basic, but can't find anything so I'm posting here.

Why does column-span not seem to work in CSS for table cells? For example, specifying the style inline like this works just fine:

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5"><i>Span!</i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1</td>
      <td>Cell 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

But if I move the colspan to CSS:

```css
.my-class td {
  column-span: all;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="my-class">
      <td class="my-class"><i>No span?</i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1</td>
      <td>Cell 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Then it does NOT work. Other style attributes (e.g. background color) DO work just fine. But column-span doesn't. What's going on here?

UPDATE: Someone suggested that it's the fact that I was using a number in my CSS (I used "column-span: 5"). But it also doesn't work if I use "all" instead, so I've update the snippet to reflect that.

SOLVED. Thanks for explaining! Didn't realize column-span CSS was not for tables.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML colspan in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403990/html-colspan-in-css)

Comment: Close, but that question is talking about non-table elements. I'm trying to understand why the colspan attribute for a td works inline but not in CSS. Thanks, though.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `column-span` CSS property is intended for multi column layouts, not for table cells as an alternative to the `colspan` HTML attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colspan attribute was created to implement the structure. Styles can't change html structure. You cannot use the column-span for table structures.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-span

Answer (score 1):

Check out W3 School's CSS column-span Property [description here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-span.asp). Suggests that CSS column span doesn't permit a number in this case. Though I may be misreading it.

Comment: Thanks, but "all" doesn't work, either. I just updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

column-span does not work for table layouts, only when using [columns](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp) layout. You should use the colspan attribute.